# @Html.DisplayFor() value not change after the postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, postback, html-helper

`@Html.DisplayFor()` value not change after send data. I read a article about this issue and say it like this; only send data what such as `EditorFor`, `TextBoxFor`, `TextAreaFor` and change state. Is it true? How can I change this value after the postback?

**View**

```
@model HRProj.Model.Person

@using(Html.BeginForm("Skills", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SkillDoc.Filename)
    <span class="file-upload">
        <span>Choose a file</span>
        <input type="file" name="file" />
    </span>
    File name : @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SkillDoc.Filename)
     <button>Upload</button>

}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Skills(int? id)
{
    Others oparations...
    var model = new Person { SkillDoc = db.GetSkillDoc().FirstOrDefault(m => m.PersonId == id) };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Skills(Person model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    Others oparations...

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SkillDoc doc = new SkillDoc();
        doc.Id = model.SkillDoc.Id;
        doc.PersonId = model.SkillDoc.PersonId;
        doc.CvDoc = (file != null) ? file.FileName : model.SkillDoc.CvDoc;
        db.SkillDocCRUD(doc, "I");

        TempData["eState"] = "The record adding successfully";

        if (file != null)
        {
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + file.FileName));
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain send data?

Comment: I am uploading a file and i want to show name that uploaded file on my form but it is swowing after page refresh.

Comment: Are you setting the same in your action method? Also please post your action method code.

Comment: @Ashian, i update my code that above.I wait ur help plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the following line inside the if block:

```
model.SkillDoc=doc;
```

Or rather redirect to Skills action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Skills", new{id= model.PersonId});
```